# Using VB.net to Display an Excell File preserving Formating

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-office

I have a project that has a need to display a Excel file in second window, but because other controls are needed, simply launching excel is not sufficient. Right now I do not know if the target machines have excel installed but I know with certainty that if they do it would be 2010, is there any method or library that allows you frame your own form around an excel window? If it helps absolutely no editing needs to occur, this will be for display purposes only, so no worries about that. Does anyone know what I need?

Comment: If you need no interaction why not just display an image of the workbook?

Comment: This is a fallback if nothing better if offered.  See [export table to outlook from excel that is blackberry friendly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9068716/973283).  The OP wanted to convert an Excel range to an HTML table but the "official" method did not work.  The official method - PublishObjects - produced poor CSS/HTML but perhaps VB.NET can cope.  My solution produces good CSS/HTML although it does not yet handle merged cells.  Something more direct would be better but HTML could be better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

what about reading the file into a dataset and attaching that to a list view or something?  You could also create your own control that inherits from a control like listview but has formatting specific to your needs

Comment: If the formatting was simpler I would, but merge cells and pictures make this task complicated painful, If it helps I post a sample file that demonstrates this, I will need some time to strip all the sensitive data out though.