# how to display excel sheet in html page

Tags: html, excel

I want to display EXCEL sheet embedded in IE with plain HTML. I have gone through other questions on stackoverflow but could not find any useful one.

Here is my html file

```
<html>
<body>
<object  width = 900 height = 500 id = "excel"  data="Issues Identified.xlsx" classid = "clsid:0002E55a-0000-0000-C000-000000000046" VIEWASTEXT  >
<param name="DisplayTitleBar" value=true />
<param name="DataType" value="CSVURL"/>
<param name="AutoFit" value="0"/>
<param name="DisplayColHeaders" value="1"/>
<param name="DisplayGridlines" value="1"/>
<param name="DisplayHorizontalScrollBar" value="1"/>
<param name="DisplayRowHeaders" value="1"/>
<param name="DisplayTitleBar" value="1"/>
<param name="DisplayToolbar" value="1"/>
<param name="DisplayVerticalScrollBar" value="1"/>
<param name="EnableAutoCalculate" value="0"/>
<param name="EnableEvents" value="0"/>
<param name="MoveAfterReturn" value="1"/>
<param name="MoveAfterReturnDirection" value="0"/>
<param name="RightToLeft" value="0"/>
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately I do not have control on the excel files that are generated. If I would have control on the excel files I could have have saved them as web pages and included in the browser. Now I doubt if by any way through above code I can embed excel sheet directly in the web browser. There are many links on web but found not find one which directly loads a excel sheet in to the browser. The ones that are there are using javascript to generate graphs and all instead of displaying an excel sheet which is already present.

When I try to load the excel sheet through above code. I get the following screen

[image]

When I use IFRAME the excel sheet is not shown as embedded file but prompting to download or open. I want it to open embedded in the internet explorer.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I would be happy to know why the question was marked down thrice.

Comment: If I am reading your question correctly, you just want to convert an Excel worksheet to HTML so it can be displayed on a website.  Try [export table to outlook from excel that is blackberry friendly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9011950/973283) which appears to be a similiar problem to yours.

Comment: Actually it was downvoted three times, upvoted once. Maybe because you appear to be asking for code without showing much effort? Or maybe because you haven't explained what's wrong with the code you posted or whether you need interactivity? Or maybe because when you do a search for "embed spreadsheet on web page" there are already several useful tutorials that come up on the first page of search results?

Comment: This might be helpful http://www.calvert.ch/maurice/2012/01/13/convert-excel-to-html-with-formatting/

Answer (score 4):

Depending on if you want it to automatically update or not, you can just save the excel spreadsheet as a PDF then embed the PDF as an object -

It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser, but you can
  [click here to
  download the PDF file.](http://www.ipack.co.uk/Assets/Timbmet/packpricingguiderc3.pdf)

It's the best way I have found for uploading.

Comment: Perhaps that isn't that usefull, since the author says that he wants to upload in plain HTML...

Answer (score 3):

You can upload it into Google Docs, and embed the Google Spreadsheet as detailed here: http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55244

Comment: I dont want my docs to be added to google docs to get it displayed on IE.

Comment: This is a cross browser way of publishing an interactive spreadsheet via HTML. It is not dependent upon proprietary software being present on the visitor's computer.

Comment: I am not looking for publishing the doc to outside world. I am looking for publishing the doc for the intranet site. I would be thankful if you could help me in figuring out whats wrong with the tag instead of specifying some unrelated solution.

Comment: This also may not meet your need, as it would rely on services external to your intranet, but here is a Microsoft article on publishing excel files to web pages: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps-help/introduction-to-excel-web-app-HA010378338.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Upload your file to Skydrive and then right click and select "Embed". They will provide iframe snippet which you can paste in your html. This works flawlessly.

Source: [Office.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/embed-an-excel-spreadsheet-on-a-web-page-FX102602477.aspx)

Comment: Not more than 5Mb :(

Comment: it cannot run macro.

Answer (score 1):

Like you, I cannot get MS Office Web Components to work.  I would not consider Google Docs since Google seems to think they own anything that passes through their hands.  I have tried MS Publish Objects but the quality of the generated html/css is truely awful.

The secret of converting an Excel worksheet to html that will display correctly on a smartphone is to create clean, lean html/css.

The structure of the HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    HEAD
  </head>
  <body>
    BODY
  </body>
</html>
```

There are useful html elements that can replace "HEAD" but it is not clear to me how you would generate them from an Excel worksheet.  They would need to be added separately.

The obvious output for a worksheet or a range is an html table so the following assumes BODY will be replaced by an html table.

The structure of an html table is:

```
<table TABLE-ATTRIBUTES>
  <tr TABLE-ROW-ATTRIBUTES>
    <td TABLE-CELL-ATTRIBUTES>CELL-VALUE</td>
    More <td>...</td> elements as necessary
  </tr>
  More <tr>...</tr> as necessary
</table>
```

Include as few TABLE-ATTRIBUTES, TABLE-ROW-ATTRIBUTES and TABLE-CELL-ATTRIBUTES as possible.  Do not set column widths in pixels.  Use css attributes rather than html attributes.

A table attribute worth considering is `style = "border-collapse: collapse;"`.  The default is `separate` with a gap around each cell.  With `collapse` the cells touch as they do with Excel.

Three table attribute worth considering are `style="background-color:aliceblue;"`, `style="color:#0000FF;"` and `style="text-align:right;"`.  With the first, you can specify the background colour to be any of the fifty or so named html colours.  With the second, you can specify the font colour to be any of 256*256*256 colours.  With the third you can right-align numeric values.

The above covers only a fraction of the formatting information that could be converted from Excel to html/css.  I am developing an add-in that will convert as much Excel formatting as possible but I hope the above helps anyone with simple requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Office 365 and OneDrive offer an embed feature. You can then include via IFrame.

I found that setting the iframe height and width to 100% works best. That way on ipad or any device for that matter it fits the screen.

```
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
    <iframe src="embed url" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [iPushPull](https://www.ipushpull.com/) to push live data direct from an Excel session to the web where you can display it in an IFRAME (or using a WordPress plugin, if applicable). The data in the frame will update whenever the data on the sheet updates.

The [iPush(...) in-cell function](https://ipushpull.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203772741) pushes data from Excel to the web.

[This support page](https://ipushpull.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203904601) describes how to embed your Excel data in your website.

Disclaimer - I work for iPushPull.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a link `<a href='file.htm'>link name</a>` or place an iframe tag, it will show the excel data on web but you can't make changes to it.

Every time you make changes in the Excel sheet you have to save again with the same name so it will replace file, and will show the result. The `<a>` tag file name extension should be `.htm`

Answer (score 0):

Note that Office Web Components are dead, see [does-office-xp-web-components-compatable-with-windows-7](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/32dd43bf-1814-4d9d-95cb-b4cd414b1ffa/does-office-xp-web-components-compatable-with-windows-7-?forum=w7itproappcompat). OWC was discontinued from XP onward for security reasons.

Since then, and only recently, Microsoft pushes Excel Web App as alternative (a poor alternative IMHO)

As a side note: Microsoft also deprecated the other way round, i.e. embedding the webbrowser control into an excel sheet, see [adding-web-browser-control-to-excel-2013](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7942c472-2b5a-4005-888f-43ece2a5800a/adding-web-browser-control-to-excel-2013?forum=officeitpro).
As an alternative Microsoft offers Office Apps (a very limited alternative with respect to interfacing Excel and IE)

Answer (score 0):

from [here](http://codebeautify.org/excel-to-html) you can easily convert your excelsheet  data into the html view

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you might try the web to send the file with proper Content-Type header and with the header like this:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="xxx.xxx"
```

Here is a discussion about these headers: [How to force files to open in browser instead of download (pdf)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-to-force-files-to-open-in-browser-instead-of-download-pdf)

Or just search on google for content-disposition.

Answer (score -4):

Try this it will work...

```
<iframe src="Tmp.XLS" width="100%" height="500"></iframe>
```

But you can not save changes that you have done...It is used only for displaying purpose..

Comment: @coolcake : ok..then other possible way is either use Google docs or you can refer this link it will help you out...  http://labnol.blogspot.in/2006/09/embed-interactive-excel-spreadsheets.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion JP. For me I dont know why but it is prompting to download or open instead of showing as embedded component.

Comment: prompting for download for me as well