# Embed an Excel file in a web page (table)

Tags: php, html, excel

Is there a simple way to embed an Excel file into a web page?
For example, say I want to import a table of 100 values into an HTML or PHP document.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I tried to use publish as webpage from excel but the excel file is linked and auto synchronised with my database.

Comment: what functionality are you looking for ? Do you want to display values only or you want the user to use all of the excel capabilities (like formulas and stuff)

Comment: Rafael i have a table in excel, i want in every page.html or page.php open get the information from Excel.

Comment: I am pleased if you are satisfied with your solution but I would not consider use of Google Docs.  Google seems to believe that can use anything that passes through their hands in any way they want.  I hope you are happy for Google to use your data for their purposes.  I suggest you look at my answer to what seems a very similar question.  [how to display excel sheet in html page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9702707/973283)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this:
http://devzone.zend.com/27/reading-and-writing-spreadsheets-with-php/

if you want only embed it:

1. upload the file to google docs
2. file> publish
3. select embed
4. copy the link
5. paste to your webpage

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fupqx/1/

Comment: This is also to read and write excel, the OP wants to embed a sheet on the webpage

Comment: Thank you :) that what i want exactly but it's a little bit complicated with all that plugins.

Comment: I need to ember a auto-synchronised file :) Mr. Astalavista not a normal file

Comment: Than sync it that way (or edit it online): http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/3_tools_to_sync_your_files_with_google_docs.php

Comment: Astalavista too complicated :'(

Comment: i success to make it http://nx.ma/Tamesna

**Thanks to Everybody here thank you a millions**