# how to show xml file from excel in HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, database, excel

How can i show excel value in a html page
within a table, and to be interactive,
when even i change the value in excel, it will save XML file,
and i want the HTML to read the new value from that XML file,
and show it in the table.

lets say, i have in excel

> table 2 by 2
>
> name, vlad
>
> age, 29

found an example for how to load xml data to html, but its not readig my xml file that created from excel.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
myFunction(this);
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "db_from_excel.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
</script>

</body>
```

I think i found the issue, when i opened the same code in firefox, it displayed all the values from xml.
But, not working in chrome.... why is that ?

Comment: what server side language are you using? If it is PHP you can have a look at phpExcel library

Comment: No, using pure html,css code.

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678127/how-to-display-excel-sheet-in-html-page

Comment: nope , thats not the case