# Any pulgins are avaliable for excel view in HTML Page

Tags: html, excel

I have to implement a HTML page which is similar to Excel view. 
Please suggest me any plugin are available?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I don't have privilege comment hence answering the question.You want excel View please elaborate your query.If you want export to Excel to you can use the following.

1. [jQuery data Table](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html).
2. [Display tags these two are good and robust solutions highly used(for jsp and jstl).](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-example/struts-display-tag-example-1.html)

Comment: Thanks Shailesh, But i need the HTML page it is having cells view similar to look and feel of excel where we can use tab, up - down - right - left arrows to navigate the cursor in the html page.

Comment: Hi I can suggest a third party tool as google spread sheet embed that object into your web page.
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java


And

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678127/how-to-display-excel-sheet-in-html-page

Comment: Got It Thanks :)