# How to embed a Word file in a html page?

Tags: html

I want to display the contents of a Word file in html without installing office. How can i display files like `.docs` or `.xlsx` on my page?

How can i show a preview of files like pdf, docx, txt, etc. in another page of the browser? Can i do this by just using html?

```html
<object data="testdoc.docx" type="application/word" width="400" height="300" ></object>
<iframe src="testdoc.docx"></iframe>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678127/how-to-display-excel-sheet-in-html-page

Comment: when the sound file on drive the beacon works well but when the sound file locally it does not work

Comment: is there a solution to display this type of file without importing it on google drive because the files are local?